# Python - Make avarage variables without 0

Tags: python, variables, sum

```
A = 0
B = 10
C = 20
N = [(A, B, C)]

Avarage = (A + B + C) / sum(1 for i in N if i != 0)
```

Avarage = 30??

Need Avarage = 15.

Any idea?

Comment: `N` is a list containing 1 tuple so `for i in N` ...i will be `(0,10,20)` and !=0....getting you 30/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `(` and `)` from your list `N`

```
a = 0
b = 10
c = 20
n = [a, b, c]

list_avg = sum(n) / sum(1 for i in n if i != 0)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> list_avg
15
```

Answer (score 1):

N is list containing tupple. So `sum(1 for i in N if i != 0)` returns 1 as there is only 1 element (a tupple) in list N.

Try:

```
A = 0
B = 10
C = 20
N = [(A, B, C)]

Avarage = (A + B + C) / sum(1 for i in N[0] if i != 0)
print Avarage
```

> 15

OR:

```
A = 0
B = 10
C = 20
N = [A, B, C]

Avarage = (A + B + C) / sum(1 for i in N if i != 0)
print Avarage
```

> 15

Comment: yep, understand now! Thx

Answer (score 0):

As stated by depperm, N is a list of one tuple, so you have in your sum only one element (which is different than 0 because it is a tuple and not an int). Otherwise you can use numpy

```
import numpy as np
average = np.mean([A, B, C])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new list of values without the zeros, then average that:

```
non_zero = [v for v in (A, B, C) if v != 0]
avg = sum(non_zero)/len(non_zero)
```